# jQuery sortable - dragged item appears far outside of list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a [jQuery Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) list that is now working - except for one annoying issue.

When I drag an item in the list, the dragged item appears far outside the list.

I have searched SO & Google for a fix for this, but I have drawn a blank.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Here is a screen shot of the issue:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
  <style>
      #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #sortable li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; height: 1.5em; }
      html>body #sortable li { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; }
      .ui-state-highlight { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; border: 3px dashed red; background: yellow; }
      .ui-sortable-helper { border: 2px dotted blue; background: lime; }
  </style>

  <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
          opacity: '0.9',
          placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
        });
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
      });
  </script>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I just tested it and it worked as you posted it. This looks like there is some error elsewhere and jquery ui cannot finish the drop. That's all the code you have when it fails?

Comment: @Gabriel there is more code - too many lines to include on post. I shall go through code and work this out. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Take a look at the console to see if are there any errors.